# FFmpeg does not download hls stream

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to download a video from an m3u8 file. I used the chrome dev tools network analyzer and copied the address from the m3u8 file.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="key://pi1CcgormCfrBeHFonx1SjYyNREActOy9x5fdSmTcQ74q9gDltGOMVTb2KT7jebRYJNU9skhE1wPp3VBgsIQhutzL9nlU7CwifAHVRX63E8abzo+8daPodXlUvN8qlXDKE8I2w37kc+UqyTG86U3Kg==",IV=0x157c77a2bc4ce357dfb893e2c01f8561
#EXTINF:6.0000,
https://contentplayer.website.com/video/4vqnGjj0L3/hls/360/segment-0.ts
....
#EXTINF:1.0667,
https://contentplayer.website.com/video/4vqnGjj0L3/hls/360/segment-219.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

So I put in ffmpeg and got a 403 forbidden error

```
[https @ 0x55c2fae84d80] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
[crypto @ 0x55c2fb11ebc0] Unable to open resource: https://contentplayer.website.com/video/4vqnGjj0L3/hls/540/segment-1.ts
[hls @ 0x55c2fae807c0] Failed to open segment 1 of playlist 0
...
```

I thought it could be because of some missing http header, so I copied the cURL command from devtools. (I copied from the request of a segment, in which I had the cloudfront authorization key)

I took all the headers from cURL and added them to ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -headers 'User-Agent: ...'
-headers 'Accept: */*' 
-headers 'Accept-Language: ...' 
-headers 'Referer: https://player....com/' 
-headers 'Origin: https://player....com' 
-headers 'Connection: keep-alive'
-headers 'Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=..; CloudFront-Signature=...; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=..; hotid=..; hmVlcIntegration=..' -headers 'Pragma: no-cache' -headers 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -headers 'TE: Trailers' 
-protocol_whitelist file,crypto,https,tcp,tls -i esse.m3u8  -map 0 -c copy output.mkv  -i link.m3u8  -map 0 -c copy output.mkv
```

However, I still receive the 403 forbidden error. When I execute the cURL command it downloads the contents of the fragment. My hypothesis was that because it is about HTTP2 the headers were not sent after the first connection, but all the important headers were added.
other ways of doing this process are also welcome

Comment: The file is protected with DRM.

Comment: @szatmary So, I reproduced the same request that the server makes and I have the AES key for decryption. If that were the problem, I would get the error when I decrypt / convert / concatenate the parts, but I am getting a 403 error from the server.